# better way for a 'For Loop' in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I'm want to use this method as a for loop but i feel like there is an easier way to do it. Not to mention it does not work, it says "called object type 'float' is not a function or function pointer.

```
CGPoint center = [Ball center];
for (center.x = 80; center.x <= 10; center.x++)
{
    center.y = ((x-280)(x-280)/266.6)+100;
};
```

Is there a better way to do this or is there a way to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: may i ask what is the point of doing this? since center.y would just become the value of the last iteration of the for loop (if your loop worked), so why have the for loop in the first place? also x is not defined inside the loop, you mean center.x dont you? not to mention the starting condition of the loop is greater than the ending condition so it wont ever enter it

Comment: @Paulw11 it wouldn't be an infinite loop. It would not enter the loop at all since the condition wouldn't be met at all.

Comment: Yeah.  Having a brain fade there

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing operator here (probably a *).

This will fix the error, but the Logic you are trying doesn't seem to be correct.

```
CGPoint center = [Ball center];
for (center.x = 80; center.x <= 10; center.x++)
{
    center.y = ((x-280)*(x-280)/266.6)+100;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to animate a view. It's much easier to just use animation for that.

```
x = 10;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        center.y = ((x-280)*(x-280)/266.6)+100;
}];
```

You can adjust duration of animation by changing 0.2 to any float number you want. You also don't have to calculate center.y with your formula, you can just put a number there.